# Can the select extension method project to a list of instantiated objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, extension-methods

I have two lists declared as follows:

```
Dim lstDBItems As New List(Of DBItem)
Dim lstAppItems As New List(Of AppItem)
```

I am trying to do something like this:

I've a function which returns List(Of AppItem):

```
Function GetAppItems() As List(Of AppItem)
'...
End Function
```

In the above function I populate lstDBItems and then write the return statement like follows:

```
Return lstDBItems.Select(Function(x)
                            dim oItem As New AppItem()
                            oItem.Property1 = x.DbProperty1
                            '...
                            Return oItem
                        End Function)
```

The weird thing is the code compiles, but on rumtime I get a type case error. What is the correct way of doing what I'm trying to achieve...?

PS: Excuse the screenshot tampering.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: this would not compile if you have Option Strict On

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ToList()` after the `Select` to have a `List(Of AppItem)` as return value

Answer (score 2):

The code *shouldn't* compile to start with. Check that you've got Option Strict on.

Once you've worked out why it's compiling when it shouldn't, your options are:

- Call [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) at the end of the query, like this:

  ```
  Return lstDBItems.Select(Function(x)
                              dim oItem As New AppItem()
                              oItem.Property1 = x.DbProperty1
                              '...
                              Return oItem
                           End Function).ToList()
  ```
- Change the return type to `IEnumerable(Of AppItem)`

Answer (score 0):

The result of the `Select` method is of type `IEnumerable(Of AppItem)`, which can not be assigned to a variable of type `List(Of AppItem`).